# Boltctl does not show my thunderbolt3 devices on Lenovo Thinkpad 25

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, thunderbolt

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad 25. When I first got the machine, I installed an older version of Ubuntu (maybe 17.10?) and the Lenovo thunderbolt 3 dock worked after disabling the thunderbolt security in BIOS. At some point after Ubuntu upgrade to 18.04 the dock stopped working. The dock still charges the laptop, but none of the ports work.

This is not my main laptop so I just decided to wait and see if a future update would fix the dock. Today I finally spent some time trying to fix this. I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.10, but that did not help.

lspci shows the thunderbolt 3 controller:

```
$ lspci -tv
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
           +-02.0  Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620
           +-14.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
           +-14.2  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
           +-15.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0
           +-16.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1
           +-1c.0-[02]----00.0  NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
           +-1c.6-[04]----00.0  Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275
           +-1d.0-[05-3d]----00.0-[06-3d]--+-00.0-[07]----00.0  Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016]
           |                               +-01.0-[08-3c]--
           |                               \-02.0-[3d]--
           +-1d.2-[3e]----00.0  Lenovo Device 0004
           +-1f.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller
           +-1f.2  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC
           +-1f.3  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
           +-1f.4  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
           \-1f.6  Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V
```

But for some reason boltctl list does not output anything. I have tried to edit the Thunderbolt 3 BIOS settings multiple times, but it seems they do not have any effect.

UPDATE:

I noticed that my dmesg contains the following text:

```
[  147.300417] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: Thunderbolt host controller is in safe mode.
[  147.300418] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: You need to update NVM firmware of the controller before it can be used.
[  147.300419] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: For latest updates check https://thunderbolttechnology.net/updates.
```

How am I supposed to update the thunderbolt 3 controller firmware? I was able to update the BIOS with an bootable memory stick, but all the other Lenovo updates are .exe files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a clonezilla clone of the original Windows disk the machine came with so I installed windows and used that to install a lot of upgrades from Microsoft and Lenovo. On windows the Lenovo Thunderbolt 3 software prompted me to install the new firmware and that went fine.

After all the upgrades I bought a new 500GB disk, put it in the machine and installed Ubuntu on that. Now Thunderbolt 3 works in Ubuntu too.

The lesson to learn, I guess, is to always have a disk with windows on it. Just in case. :-(

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. What helped was using the correct port on the laptop (see [here](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T/T480-connection-to-Thunderbolt-3-Dock/td-p/4058043). Basically, there are two ports in which the connectors fits, one is the power hub for the charger (close to the escape key), and one is slightly more to the front (with a lightning logo). Connecting the dock with this port, made everything work.

Hope this helps